# Applications of Model Theory and Category Theory

Tags: category-theory, model-theory, game-theory, applications, descriptive-complexity

Do Model Theory and Category Theory have applications in solving Complexity and Game Theory problems in computer science?
I am looking for an example of these...(If there is any...)

Answer (score 0):

I am not well-versed enough in the subject to posit any relation between Complexity Theory and Category Theory, but [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/game+theory) contains some references to Game Theory. nLab is a wonderful reference for Category Theory in my opinion, and is quite well-organized in its references!